# Infinite ListView on iOS after refreshing jumps to first item

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have been created ListView that has infinite scrolling with help on ObservableRangeCollection. It works good on Android, but on iOS it jumps to start whenever it adds new items. Paginating is done with behavior. ListView is a FlowListView. 
Here is XAML:

```
...
FlowItemsSource="{Binding Profiles.Result}
...
<controls:FlowListView.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:FlowListViewPaginating
          Command="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
          Converter="{StaticResource ItemVisibilityConverter}">
        </behaviors:FlowListViewPaginating>
      </controls:FlowListView.Behaviors>
...
```

Behavior:

```
public class FlowListViewPaginating : Behavior<FlowListView>
    {
        public FlowListView AssosiatedObject { get; private set; }

        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(DelegateCommand<Profile>), typeof(FlowListViewPaginating), null);

        public static readonly BindableProperty InputConverterProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Converter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(FlowListViewPaginating), null);


        public DelegateCommand<Profile> Command
        {
            get { return ( DelegateCommand<Profile> )GetValue(CommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public IValueConverter Converter
        {
            get { return ( IValueConverter )GetValue(InputConverterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InputConverterProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(FlowListView bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

            AssosiatedObject = bindable;
            bindable.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
            bindable.ItemAppearing += OnItemAppearing;
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(FlowListView bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);

            bindable.BindingContextChanged -= OnBindingContextChanged;
            bindable.ItemAppearing -= OnItemAppearing;
            AssosiatedObject = null;
        }

        private void OnItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
        {
            var flowListView = ( FlowListView )sender;

            if ( flowListView.IsRefreshing ) return;
            if ( Command == null ) return;

            var parameter = Converter.Convert(e, typeof(object), null, null) as Profile;
            if ( Command.CanExecute(parameter) )
                Command.Execute(parameter);
        }

        protected void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnBindingContextChanged();
        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();

            BindingContext = AssosiatedObject.BindingContext;
        }


    }
```

Converter for Behavior:

```
public class ItemVisibilityEventConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var eventArgs = value as ItemVisibilityEventArgs;
            var collection = eventArgs?.Item as System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object>;
            return collection[0];
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

My collection:

```
public NotifyTask<ObservableRangeCollection<Profile>> Profiles { get; set; }
```

`NotifyTask` has nothing to do with the collection. It is just a wrapper.

A method where I add items:

```
private async Task OnLoadMore(Profile lastProfile)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            _pageNumber++;
            Profiles.Result.AddRange(await _manager.GetProfilesAsync(_parameters.NextPage()));
            IsBusy = false;
        }
```

Comment: What is a `FlowListView`? It's not part of Xamarin.Forms

Comment: @Krumelur Here it is: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView

Comment: You should consider raising an issue over there. https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/issues

Comment: @Krumelur
Ok, I did it right now.

Comment: @YuraBabiy : One method to solve this could be by having a constant size of the FlowListView.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith Do you mean count of items or width? Please add some details

Comment: @YuraBabiy : Well I was facing a similar issue. I do not mean of individual items but rather the entire control. And both height and width. Like you can try setting the Horizontal and Vertical option as FillAndExpand. Keep a background color to test it out so as to check if the height is increasing dynamically as the items are added.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith I had it set to FillAndExpand, so it will not work for me. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

- You should use `FlowItemAppearing` / `FlowItemDissappearing` instead `ItemAppearing` / `ItemDissappearing`. It provides actual `FlowListView` items.
- There's an example with adding / removing items to the list, here:

  - https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/blob/master/Samples/DLToolkitControlsSamples/SamplesFlowListView/UpdateItemsPage.xaml
  - https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/blob/master/Samples/DLToolkitControlsSamples/SamplesFlowListView/UpdateItemsPageModel.cs

Those examples won't scroll your list on iOS / Android when items are updated. Please be sure to use the newest nuget package.

XAML:

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="false"
    FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}"
    FlowItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

</flv:FlowListView>
```

View model:

```
public UpdateItemsPageModel()
{
    AddCommand = new BaseCommand((arg) =>
    {
        insertId++;
        Items.Insert(10, new SimpleItem() { Title = string.Format("New {0}", insertId) }); 
    });

    RemoveCommand = new BaseCommand((arg) =>
    {
        Items.RemoveAt(10);
    });
}

public ObservableCollection<object> Items
{
    get { return GetField<ObservableCollection<object>>(); }
    set { SetField(value); }
}
```

Comment: I updated flow listview nuget to the last stable, replaced events like you said, and tried to add elements with insert. And there is my observation:
- if I add one item like in your sample, then it works, but if this item doesn't download then it crashes with this error: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSRangeException Reason: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]:
If I add items in cycle with insert or add or addRange than will be the same as before.

Comment: But I noticed that if exactly before next page I have a finger on display (emulator), then it works. It hasn't refresh indicator and just adds items in silence. But when there is an indicator, then it jumps to the first page. 
On Android, all works like a charm. With indicator, without jumps, and with any code.

Comment: Could you make a reproduction and send it to me? My email is on my github account page. I'll try to fix this, if it's a bug :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it in the demo because I get items from rest API and have massive XAML page with many elements. Could you just collaborate with me? I will send you code snippets and screenshots in private.

Comment: So what you think, Daniel?

Comment: Daniel, I tested it with simple listview and problem is still there. So it is not about FlowListView. Sorry me for your disturb. I just think that you are the one of not many, who knows deep of listview.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround in my situation. Here is code, when it works fine:

```
private void OnLoadMore(Profile lastProfile)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            _pageNumber++;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var newItems = await _manager.GetProfilesAsync(_parameters.NextPage());
                Profiles.Result.AddRange(newItems);
            });

            IsBusy = false;
        }
```

There is still another issue. It doesn't show a loading indicator. On both iOS and Android. If I put rest of code of the method in the main thread, or move GetProfilesAsync from the main thread, it will jump like it was before.